# Java - how to select previous day from the calendar? or how to get previous date in JAVA?

Tags: java

I want to select the previous day in a calendar. For example, if I have 02-28-2018 I need to set 27 automatically.

I have tried the below code but it fails when the date is 1st.

```
String currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd").format(new Date());
int previousDay = Integer.parseInt(currentDate) - 1;
```

Answer (score 3):

There is an easy way to do this in Java 8

```
int previousDay = LocalDate.now().minusDays(1).getDayOfMonth();
```

For `LocalDate` Reference see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html)

Hope this Helps!

Answer (score 1):

If using Java7 you can use Calendar

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -1);

System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("dd").format(cal.getTime()));
```

But for Java8 see http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html

Also a back-port for Java 6 & Java 7: [*ThreeTen-Backport*](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).